# How to decode a rc2 cyphertext that has been encoded in base64 with an IV?

Tags: encryption, openssl, password-encryption, malware, php-openssl

I continue to get bad magic number. I do not know what this means.

here is what I am inputting to the CLI:

```
openssl enc -d -rc2-cbc -base64 -k AUvS8jou0Z9K7Bf9 -iv 6f73575664616a4f0d0a -in input.enc -out output.dec
```

inside of the input.enc I have:

```
my7wR7eAbxbng06i0+kGjnMJ+QPavxa5JKG7LbMb2BLbH0hld/R1eQ==
```

**Background information:**

I am analyzing the carberp botnet malware and I seem to be hitting an issue where the encrypted data is not being decrypted. After much investigating I found that the malware sends a http post with an encrypted value. This value is rc2 encrypted and encoded in base64 with the IV at the ends of the post

here is an excerpt:
Value in post:

```
osWVmy7wR7eAbxbng06i0+kGjnMJ+QPavxa5JKG7LbMb2BLbH0hld/R1eQdajO==
```

IV is the first 4 and last 4 characters of the value (excluding the ==)

```
osWVdajO
```

the encrypted message should be:

```
my7wR7eAbxbng06i0+kGjnMJ+QPavxa5JKG7LbMb2BLbH0hld/R1eQ
```

to make it base64 it looks like:

```
my7wR7eAbxbng06i0+kGjnMJ+QPavxa5JKG7LbMb2BLbH0hld/R1eQ==
```

The password I used (when configuring) is

```
AUvS8jou0Z9K7Bf9
```

The output should be:

```
id=AdminPanelEchoKey020F504D0263A5D01
```

Every time I try to input it into openssl_decrypt in php it returns an empty string (don't know why).